# Get request header value on cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm new to cypress, here is what i want to do

do a first simple request : `cy.visit('url')`
When the browser will do some request, i want to get one of the request's header, so what i did :

```html
cy.intercept({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '**/admin/user/informations',
}).as('xsrfResponse');
cy.visit('url')
   .wait('@xsrfResponse', { timeout: 20000 })
   .then((xhr) => {
    //doesn't work
    let xsrf = JSON.stringify(xhr.responseHeaders.token)
    cy.log(xsrf)
    })
```

Any help to get the request header value ? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with  xhr.request.headers['token']